# Running multiple programs in the background and checking their return value

Tags: shell, scripting, background-process

suppose I want to run a few (say, three) programs at once, like this

```
program1 & program2 & program3 &
```

if I want to know their `pid's`, I think the best way is to store them, like this

```
program1 &
pid1=$!
program2 &
pid2=$!
...
```

But now, what if I want to know if they have ended and if so, what value they returned? Something like this:

```
if [ program1 has ended ]; then
    do something with its return value
fi
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

```
# launch child process in background
launch_child_process &

# grab child's pid and store it (use array if several)
pid=$!

# later, wait for termination
wait $pid
# show return code from wait, which is actually the return code of the child
echo "Child return code:" $?
```

With several children, you can of course loop to wait on each pid and collect the corresponding return code. You get out of that loop when the last child ends.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to write a message to a log file

Say, for program 1, do something like :

```
#!/bin/bash
.
.
your stuff
.
.
end_time==$(date)
echo "program1 ended at $end_time" > program1_log
```

Another soultion would be to create an empty file to mark the process end

```
#!/bin/bash
.
.
your stuff
.
.
echo $? > /some/path/program1_ended #storing the exit value
#disadvantage is that you can't verify if intermediate commands failed.
```

Then to check do

```
   if [ -e /some/path/program1_ended ]
   then
   exit_status=$( </some/path/program1_ended )
   rm /some/path/program1_ended #Deleting the file, getting ready for next run
   .
   .
   Do something
   else
   echo "program1 has not ended yet"
  fi
```

Comment: I don't understand. The value `$?` returns the exit value of the last program terminated (?), so I won't know which one it'll be

Comment: @Jytug : In your script, it will give you the exit status of the last command. As I told you, if any intermediate command failed, you can't detect this using this method.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX sh isn't very good at handling multiple background processes. The basic tool is the `wait` builtin, which blocks until a background process exits. But `wait` with no argument waits until *all* background processes have exited, and returns the exit status of the last process that exited; the exit status of the other subprocesses is lost.

You can set a trap for SIGCHLD, which is the signal that is raised when a process's child exits. This executes code whenever a subprocess exits. However you don't necessarily get to know which subprocess exited or what its return status is. Different shells behave differently.

ATT ksh93 (not mksh or pdksh!) is the only one among the common shells that behaves usefully with SIGCHLD traps. It sets `$!` to the PID of the process that exited and `$?` to its return status.

```
#!/bin/ksh
trap 'Process $! (${subprocesses[$!]}) exited with status $?' CHLD
typeset -A subprocesses
program1 & subprocesses[$!]='program1'
program2 & subprocesses[$!]='program2'
wait
```

If you use another shell, put any post-treatment in the subprocess.

```
#!/bin/sh
{ program1; echo "program1 exited with status $?"; } &
{ program2; echo "program2 exited with status $?"; } &
wait
```

Or use a more capable language such as Perl, Python, Ruby, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in which order the processes will end, approximately, you can use `wait <pid>` to wait for it to exit, and the `wait` command will inherit the exit status of the waited-for process. eg

```
if wait $pid1
then echo "$pid1 was ok"
else echo "$pid1 failed with code $?"
fi
```

If you dont know the order you can wait for any of them with `wait -n $pid1 $pid2 ...`, and get the exit code similarly, but you will not know which process it was that ended, but it is useful if you just need to know if any failed.

Comment: "wait" also works for process that have already ended, so you can wait on each process in sequence and recover each return code. The actual sequence of wait is irrelevant the only thing which is true is that you will exit that sequence more or less when the last subprocess ends.